# Cannot fetch cloud configurations when upgrading Spring Boot from 2.1.x to 2.3.3

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

My project (microservices) are using Spring Boot 2.1.x and Spring Cloud `Greenwich.SR5`. I want to upgrade to Spring Boot 2.3.x (`2.3.3 RELEASE`) and Spring Cloud (`Hoxton.SR8`) but I face the issue that service cannot fetch information from the cloud config server(`-Dspring.cloud.config.uri=http://config.abc`).

I found that https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/2.2.x/spring-cloud-config-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/client/ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java#L261 is sending `V2_JSON` not `application/json`.

Anyone can give me some solution or workaround?

Comment: What does "can not fetch" mean? Are there any errors? Has the config server been upgraded as well?

Comment: Mean that my service cannot fetch from the configuration server. Sure centralization server still using 2.1.x that why It's application/json, not V2_JSON. I'm trying to find some way to send application/json instead of V2_JSON then I think my service can fetch cloud configuration

Comment: "Are there any errors?" or anything in logs?

Comment: Yes, It has exceptions but It's just rest template exception said that media type is not supported. because my cloud centralize-config still using spring-boot 2.1.x (I cannot touch it). It's accepting application/json but from spring boot 2.2.x It sends V2_JSON that why I face issue media type is not supported. I'm trying to overwrite ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator to send application/json instead of V2_JSON. If possible I think it should work

Comment: Can you file an issue at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/?

Answer (score 1):

I've raised an issue here, hopefully, It will helpful
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1715